# ajax response is integer and I can't handle it , when I alert it i get [object , object ]

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url_delete_admin_privilidge,
        data: postData,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            setAdminResponse(response);
            alert("success");

        },
        fail: function() {
            alert("fail");
            console.log("fail");

        }
    });
```

- the response of this request is 1 for success and 0 or 2 or 3 for another some cases if not success it always enter on fail method and status of request is 400 (bad request) I cant handle these cases.
- I handled responses and cases of request on `setAdminResponse();` which code is always enter on else cases.

  ```
  function setAdminResponse(response) {
  if (response === 1)
  {
      $("#Response").text("success").css("color", "green");
  }
  else if (response === 0)
  {
      $("#Response").text("user not found in circle").css("color", "red");
  } else if (response === 2) {
      $("#Response").text("user is already admin in circle").css("color", "red");

  } else if (response === 3)
  {
      $("#Response").text("only owner can do it").css("color", "red");
  } else
  {
      $("#Response").text("an error happenes").css("color", "red");
  }

  }
  ```

Comment: can you write out the output of console logging?

Comment: It is `error:` not `fail:`. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: what is stored in `url_delete_admin_privilidge`

Comment: url_delete_admin_privilidge is url which execute some code in backEnd and return the status of process not hold any data

Comment: Is the response `Content-Type` `application/json`? Maybe you need to add `response.d`?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url_delete_admin_privilidge,
        data: postData,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            setAdminResponse(response);
            alert("success");

        },
        error: function() {
            alert("fail");
            console.log("fail");

        }
    });
```

Function:

```
function setAdminResponse(response) {
if (response === '1')
{
    $("#Response").text("success").css("color", "green");
}
else if (response === '0')
{
    $("#Response").text("user not found in circle").css("color", "red");
} else if (response === '2') {
    $("#Response").text("user is already admin in circle").css("color", "red");

} else if (response === '3')
{
    $("#Response").text("only owner can do it").css("color", "red");
} else
{
    $("#Response").text("an error happenes").css("color", "red");
}

}
```

It now compares string, because in most cases the response is returned as a string unless otherwise specified